# Argument 3: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Text.Encoding'

Tags: c#, zip, launcher

I am using `System.IO.Compression` and using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory`. I saw a guy use 3 arguments, two strings and a bool. When I try to copy exactly what he did, I get thrown an error. I know `ZipFile` can either be an encoding or a bool, but I want it to be a bool. Is there something I need to change?

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Here is the code for anyone that may think it'll help. Here is the video I am following as well. It has a time stamp of where he was typing the ZipFile line. https://youtu.be/JIjZQo03YdA?t=420

```
private void DownloadGameCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string onlineVersion = ((Version)e.UserState).ToString();
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(gameZip, rootPath, true);
        File.Delete(gameZip);

        File.WriteAllText(versionFile, onlineVersion);

        VersionText.Text = onlineVersion;
        Status = LauncherStatus.READY;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = LauncherStatus.FAILED;
        MessageBox.Show($"Error finishing download: {ex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to / use the API reference. That’s what you get. There are occasionally small deviations between platforms. Anyway - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory should be type-valid (where the boolean 3rd parameter = overwriteFiles), assuming the other two arguments are indeed strings and environment is as claimed.

Comment: What do you want the third parameter of true to mean?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of gameZip and rootPath?

Comment: @David.Warwick the true means to overwriteFiles.

Comment: @KlausGütter the gameZip is the sourceArchiveFileName and the rootPath is destinationDirectoryName.

Answer (score 1):

I was using .NET Framework instead of .NET Core. Sorry for wasting your time guys! I forgot .NET Framework and .NET Core are two completely different things.